# How to get the currently open chrome tabs on ubuntu, in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, browser, html

There are times that I may have dozens of tabs open at one time. How would I go about pulling all open tabs, windows, and pages into a python script?

Comment: what does "pulling all open tabs, windows, and pages into a python script" mean?

Comment: A list of every current open page.